# Is this Coleman Recessed Heater Model #69 gas or electric?

Tags: heating

Is the Coleman Recessed Heater Model# 69 gas or electric?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### The AGA logo and the nameplate specs are dead giveaways

This is a gas heater -- the nameplate specs are in BTUs, while an electric unit is specified in watts.  Furthermore, it's AGA certified -- the American *Gas* Association doesn't deal with electric heaters!